# winepath truncation issue

Tags: 14.04, wine

I have followed the directions on multiple websites.  I created a command in the registry :

default
    /bin/sh/ /run_linux eog \"%1\"

I created the following code in the run_linux script

```
#!/bin/sh
eog $1 "`wine winepath -u "$2"`"
echo $1 "`wine winepath -s "$2"`" >> /tmp/output
```

In the registry i have tried....

```
\"%1\" it sends NOTHING to the script.
%1 it sends everything up to the first space of the file URL.
```

Now, i understand why %1 is only sending up to the first space of the file URL, as i did that more for testing, but when i use \"%1\" nothing pushes through.

Example output

with registry command set to : /bin/sh /run_linux eog %1 
Out put  ->  eog /home/myname/.wine/dosdevices/c:/users/myname/My

with registry command set to : /bin/sh /run_linux eog \"%1\" 
Out put  ->  eog

What the heck am i doing wrong?

I even manually typed the full path calling the script directly and it works, so I believe the issue is in the registry command.

Comment: I might also add i typed in the full path into the registry so as to not even use the %1, and if i surround it with \" if fails, and if i do not surround it with \" it outputs up until the first space.

Answer (score 0):

It ended up being so simple :
I was editing the registry through regedit, and there you only need
to put it within quotes without the back-slash.

Just put quotes with out the \ character and then it worked.

Example :

```
eog "%1"
```